# useState setmethod is updating inside useEffect but not reflecting the result outside

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I was trying to use `react-native-contacts` library to display my contacts in the app. I am able to establish the connection and name of every person is visible when I do a `console.log`.
I have created this usestate hook

```
let [con,setContacts] = useState([])
```

What I want is to add all the names along with index to this array like this

```
{name:"adi",index:"1"}
```

I also did this inside a `useEffect` hook, but the issue is that when I call `console.log(con.length)` it prints the total value is 243.When I call the same method outside the `useEffect` it shows 1. It seems that the `usestate` is not updating outside.

CODE::

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

// Import all required component
import {
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

const ContactScreen = function(){

  let [con, setContacts] = useState([]);
  //console.log("after usestate")
  useEffect(()=>{
    PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
      {
        'title': 'Contacts',
        'message': 'This app would like to view your contacts.',
        'buttonPositive': 'Please accept bare mortal'
      }
    )
    Contacts.getAll().then(contacts => {
      // contacts returned
      console.log("heyyyyyy===================")
      contacts.map((item,index)=>{
        //console.log(item.displayName)
        let nobj={name:item.displayName,index:index}
        //console.log(nobj)
        let arr=con.push(nobj)
        //console.log(arr)
        setContacts([arr])
        console.log(con.length);
        //console.log(con);
        console.log("=================================================");
      })
    })
  },[])
  //issue ==>> displays 1
  console.log(con.length);
 
    return(
        <View style={style.container}>
            <Text>
                this is contact screen
            </Text>
            <Text>{con.length}</Text>
            
        </View>
    )
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        margin:10,
        backgroundColor: '#ebebeb'
      }
})

export default ContactScreen;
```

Output:

output shows that state is updating inside use effect

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Firstly you should map the contacts in your designed form. After that when it's mapped then just set the array of contacts in one line. Check out the my following solution.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

// Import all required component
import {
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

const ContactScreen = function(){

  let [con, setContacts] = useState([]);
  //console.log("after usestate")
  useEffect(()=>{
    PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
      {
        'title': 'Contacts',
        'message': 'This app would like to view your contacts.',
        'buttonPositive': 'Please accept bare mortal'
      }
    )
    Contacts.getAll().then(contacts => {
      // contacts returned
     const modififiedContacts = contacts.map((item,index)=>{
         return {name:item.displayName,index:index}
      });
     setContacts(modifiedContacts);
    })
  },[])
  //issue ==>> displays 1
  console.log(con.length);
 
    return(
        <View style={style.container}>
            <Text>
                this is contact screen
            </Text>
            <Text>{con.length}</Text>
            
        </View>
    )
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        margin:10,
        backgroundColor: '#ebebeb'
      }
})

export default ContactScreen;
```

Comment: I am very grateful to you sir.
Thank you so much for helping me.